После ввода операции бот ничего не делает
Программирую телеграм-бота с помощью библиотеки telebot. Добавлял команду калькулятора, всё сделал правильно (я проверял) но после ввода операции ничего не происходит.
Вот код функции операции:
def operation_message(message):
    operation = message.text
    if operation == "+":
        global num1
        global num2
        result = num1 + num2
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Я уже решил! Ответ:")
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, result)


Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.
